# Удалить строчки из DataGridView по определенному условию

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Есть DataGridView в котором есть несколько строк, требуется удалить строки с определенным значением.

Я пробовал через foreach и через for проходить по всем строкам, но после удаления одной строки происходит сдвиг в индексации и при последующем обхождении что-то может не удалиться...

Получается, что бы правильно удалить, я должен обойти весь DataGridView и собрать все объекты в List, а потом через foreach по этому List кидать элементы в `DataGridView.Rows.Remove(row)`?
Или можно как-то иначе?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DataGridView` рассчитан в большей степени на привязку внешних данных, чем на ручное управление содержимым.

С циклом `foreach` действительно будет проблема, т.к. он не учитывает, что коллекция, для которой он выполняется, будет изменена в процессе выполнения. Так что этот вариант отпадает сразу.

В прямом цикле `for` по индексам коллекции, при удалении элемента, нужно уменьшать значение счетчика на 1. Тогда следующий элемент будет выбираться правильно, без пропусков.

Обратный `for`, который у вас сработал, будет правильно работать без модификаций.

Ну и самый правильный вариант на мой взгляд, это все таки вносить изменения не в `DataGridView`, а в привязанную коллекцию, которая содержит отображаемые данные. Даже если это банальный `List`, то можно одним linq-запросом `RemoveAll(<условие>)` решить вашу задачу в одну строчку кода.

Comment: про обратный `for` ошибся и ни кто не заметил даже... грустно, уже поправил

Answer (score 1):

Воспользовался циклом `for` и обход коллекции не с начала, а с конца и сработало.

Answer (score 1):

Нормальная практика это работать с источником данных, и грид только рефшрешить/апдейдить.  Если напрямую с ровами, то вы уже правильно заметили нужно идти с конца, чтобы к правильным индексам обращались.